# How to correctly downgrade geth from 1.6.0 to 1.5.9 on Win 10

Tags: go-ethereum

The question is self-explanatory, I believe. I saw how to downgrade on Mac or Linux, but  ironically I have geth running of Win 10 machine as well (do not ask why?)

In geth version `1.6.0.-stable-facc47cs` the key word seems to be not `stable` but `facc`... at least on my PC :-)
It throws out too often.